# laravel 9 (how can i make this code better..more compact)

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 lists from 3 different stages of a client. I want to list all the clients, but separated by the stages of those clients.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Title and Top Buttons Start -->
    <div class="page-title-container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Title Start -->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
            
                <!-- @include('_layout.breadcrumb',['breadcrumbs'=>$breadcrumbs]) -->
            </div>
            <!-- Title End -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Title and Top Buttons End -->

    <!-- Content Start -->
    <div>
    <div class="row">
                <!-- Buttons Start -->
                <div class="col-xl-6 mb-5">
                    <section class="scroll-section" id="buttons">
                    
                        <!-- Lista Prospecção  -->
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">                               
                            <h2 class="small-title">Prospecção</h2>                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="scroll-out">
                            <div class="scroll-by-count" data-count="5">
                            @foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', '1') as $cliente) 

                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                    <div class="row g-0 sh-14 sh-md-10">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card-body pt-0 pb-0 h-700">
                                                <div class="row g-0 h-100 align-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-flex flex-column mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <div>{{$cliente->nome}} </div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate"><a href="https://wa.me/55{{$cliente->contato}}">{{$cliente->contato}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate">{{$cliente->mes}}/{{$cliente->ano}}</div>                                                                                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fim Lista Prospecção -->
                        <br />
                        <!-- Lista Necessidade do Cliente  -->
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">                               
                            <h2 class="small-title">Necessidade do Cliente</h2>                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="scroll-out">
                            <div class="scroll-by-count" data-count="5">
                            
                            
                            @foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', '2') as $cliente) 
                          
                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                    <div class="row g-0 sh-14 sh-md-10">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card-body pt-0 pb-0 h-700">
                                                <div class="row g-0 h-100 align-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-flex flex-column mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <div>{{$cliente->nome}} </div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate"><a href="https://wa.me/55{{$cliente->contato}}">{{$cliente->contato}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate">{{$cliente->mes}}/{{$cliente->ano}}</div>                                                                                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fim Lista Necessidade do Cliente -->
                        <br />
                        <!-- Lista Marcou Consulta  -->
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">                               
                            <h2 class="small-title">Marcou Consulta</h2>                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="scroll-out">
                            <div class="scroll-by-count" data-count="5">
                            @foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', '3') as $cliente) 
                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                    <div class="row g-0 sh-14 sh-md-10">
                                        <!-- <div class="col-auto h-100">
                                            <img src="/img/product/small/product-2.webp" alt="alternate text" class="card-img card-img-horizontal sw-11" />
                                        </div> -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card-body pt-0 pb-0 h-700">
                                                <div class="row g-0 h-100 align-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-flex flex-column mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <div>{{$cliente->nome}} </div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate"><a href="https://wa.me/55{{$cliente->contato}}">{{$cliente->contato}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate">{{$cliente->mes}}/{{$cliente->ano}}</div>                                                                                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fim Lista Marcou Consulta -->
                        <br />
                        <!-- Lista Apresentou Proposta  -->
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">                               
                            <h2 class="small-title">Apresentou Proposta</h2>                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="scroll-out">
                            <div class="scroll-by-count" data-count="5">
                            @foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', '4') as $cliente) 
                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                    <div class="row g-0 sh-14 sh-md-10">
                                        <!-- <div class="col-auto h-100">
                                            <img src="/img/product/small/product-2.webp" alt="alternate text" class="card-img card-img-horizontal sw-11" />
                                        </div> -->
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card-body pt-0 pb-0 h-700">
                                                <div class="row g-0 h-100 align-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-flex flex-column mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <div>{{$cliente->nome}} </div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate"><a href="https://wa.me/55{{$cliente->contato}}">{{$cliente->contato}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate">{{$cliente->mes}}/{{$cliente->ano}}</div>                                                                                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                          
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fim Lista Apresentou Proposta -->
                        <br />
                    </section>
                </div>
                <!-- Buttons End -->
            </div>                 
    </div>
    <!-- Content End -->
</div>
```

The code is working.

```
@foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', '1') as $cliente) 
@endforeach
```

This is the main loop.
I have to make a `foreach` inside this foreach?
Showing each "etapa" (stage) that my client is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Title and Top Buttons Start -->
    <div class="page-title-container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Title Start -->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
            
                <!-- @include('_layout.breadcrumb',['breadcrumbs'=>$breadcrumbs]) -->
            </div>
            <!-- Title End -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Title and Top Buttons End -->

    <!-- Content Start -->
    <div>
    <div class="row">
                <!-- Buttons Start -->
                <div class="col-xl-6 mb-5">
                    <section class="scroll-section" id="buttons">
                        
                    
                        <!-- Listas  -->
                        
                            @php                                        
                            $etapa = [
                                '1' => 'Prospecção',
                                '2' => 'Necessidade do Cliente',
                                '3' => 'Marcou Consulta',
                                '4' => 'Apresentou Proposta',
                                '5' => 'Negócio Fechado',
                                '6' => 'Negócio Perdido',
                                '7' => 'Oportunidades Futuras'
                            ];                                            
                                                                     
                        @endphp
                        @foreach ($etapa as $keyetapa => $e)

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">                               
                                <h2 class="small-title">{{ $e }}</h2>                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="scroll-out">
                                <div class="scroll-by-count" data-count="5">                                

                            @foreach ($clientes->where('etapa', $keyetapa) as $cliente) 

                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                    <div class="row g-0 sh-14 sh-md-10">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card-body pt-0 pb-0 h-700">
                                                <div class="row g-0 h-100 align-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 d-flex flex-column mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <div>{{$cliente->nome}} </div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate"><a href="https://wa.me/55{{$cliente->contato}}">{{$cliente->contato}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="text-small text-muted text-truncate">{{$cliente->mes}}/{{$cliente->ano}}</div>                                                                                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                        @endforeach
                        
                    </section>
                </div>
                <!-- Buttons End -->
            </div>                 
    </div>
    <!-- Content End -->
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).